# Change mouse position when I move my player

Tags: xna, monogame

I've set my camera following my player, but I have a problem.

When my player moves, the vector changes obviously but not my mouse position.

I have to calculate the mouse angles of where I shoot my bullets and directions so it becomes very weird if my mouse position does not change but my vector does.

Really have no idea what to do, even after searching all over the internet.

Code for when I shoot:

```
                v.X = (float)Math.Sqrt((5 * 5) / (1 + ((dy * dy) / (dx * dx))));
                v.Y = (float)Math.Sqrt(5 * 5 - v.X * v.X);
                if(Mouse.GetState().X > vector.X && Mouse.GetState().Y > vector.Y )
                {
                    bullets.Add(new Bullet(bulletTexture, vector.X, vector.Y, v.X, v.Y, 1));
                }
                if (Mouse.GetState().X < vector.X && Mouse.GetState().Y > vector.Y)
                {
                    bullets.Add(new Bullet(bulletTexture, vector.X, vector.Y, -v.X, v.Y, 1));
                }
                if (Mouse.GetState().X > vector.X && Mouse.GetState().Y < vector.Y)
                {
                    bullets.Add(new Bullet(bulletTexture, vector.X, vector.Y, v.X, -v.Y, 1));
                }
                if (Mouse.GetState().X < vector.X && Mouse.GetState().Y < vector.Y)
                {
                    bullets.Add(new Bullet(bulletTexture, vector.X, vector.Y, -v.X, -v.Y, 1));
                }
```

Player facing where the mouse shoots:

```
 mosAngle = (float)Math.Atan((Mouse.GetState().Y - vector.Y )    / (Mouse.GetState().X - vector.X));
        if(Mouse.GetState().LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {         
            if (Mouse.GetState().Y < vector.Y && Math.Abs(mosAngle) > Math.PI / 4)
            {
                texture = backAnim;                
            }
            else if (Mouse.GetState().Y > vector.Y && Math.Abs(mosAngle) > Math.PI / 4)
            {
                texture = frontAnim;             
            }
            else if (Mouse.GetState().X > vector.X)
            {
                texture = rightAnim;          
            }
            else
            {
                texture = leftAnim;   
            }
```

Camera class:

```
class Camera 
{
    private Matrix transform;
    private Viewport view;
    private Vector2 centre, camPos;
    public Matrix Transform
    {
        get { return transform; }
    }

    public Camera(Viewport view) 
    {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            camPos.X += 2f;

        }
        if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            camPos.X -= 2f;

        }
        if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            camPos.Y -= 4f;

        }
        if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            camPos.Y += 4f;

        }
        centre = new Vector2(camPos.X, camPos.Y);
        transform = Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(1, 1, 0)) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-centre.X, -centre.Y, 0));
    }
```

I'm not sure what I should do in order for the code for shooting and facing the same direction where player shoots to work.

Comment: Can you explain what `vector` does? You've said that the vector does change, but I've no idea what you meant by that. can you also show a screenshot how the problem currently looks like?

Answer (score 1):

> When my player moves, the vector changes obviously but not my mouse position.

That is because the mouse position is always the position within the window and not - like your player - in the game world.

So you need to deal with two different positions like mouseWindowPosition (which you get from your mouseState and mouseWorldPosition which you get by adding the mouseWindowPosition and your camera position.